# Songs similar to Solveig's Song

Tags: classical-music, similar-artists

Not being an avid listener of classical music in general, I generally find it tough to find classical music I really like. The entire Peer Gynt suite I love very much though, with a particular fondness of Solveig's Song (the versions sang by Anna Netrebko or Lucia Popp in especially).

Now I usually try to take it upon myself to find similar music to music I like. However in this case this has proven to be particular hard.

Would anyone know of any songs that have the mellow vocals and same kind of quality to them? A lot of thanks in advance:).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [recommendations are off-topic](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-we-accept-listening-recommendation-questions).

Comment: I didn't know that. May I ask, what purpose does the similar artists tag serve if not for recommendations?

Comment: You may also want to pursue the question in the forum's chat room

Comment: @BCdotWEB, one of most upvoted questions here is a recommendation question (and from a mod): https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/649/bands-in-the-vein-of-dream-theater. I think OP added enough details for the question not being too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- ["Habenera"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYxTbGTqlu4) from
  Bizet's *Carmen*
- Offenbach's ["Barcarolle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hdc2zNgJIpY) from *Tales of Hoffman*
- "[O Mio Babbino Caro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6bSrGbak1g)" from Puccini's
  *Gianni Schicchi*.

These are three famous arias with female vocalists.

Comment: Thank you very much, those are three very nice songs indeed. I like "O Mio Babbino Caro" in particular.

Comment: Try also number 5 of Villa-Lobos "Bachianas Brasileiras". Soprano soloist and an orchestra of cellos.  <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anxdAcilnsM>

Comment: @Angst - you could make this your own answer

Answer (score 2):

Try also number 5 of Villa-Lobos "Bachianas Brasileiras". Soprano soloist and an orchestra of cellos.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anxdAcilnsM.