# History of musical instruments in classical music

Tags: history, reference-request

I recently read a bit about how the harpsichord was replaced by the piano, but the text did not go in depth into the reasons behind the change.

I am looking for resources to learn what instruments have been in use in classical music. Also, how have the instruments evolved? For instance, I guess the materials we make the strings for string instruments out of today is not the same materials they used to be made out of four centuries ago.

More importantly, I want to know why the changes happened. What advantages did the new instruments have?

Of course, this question is quite broad. So, I am just asking for resources like websites and books. Also, I am restricting my question to the time period from the renaissance to, but not including, the 20th century.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is usually off-topic on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Well, "book-recommendation" is its own tag on both Mathematics and History of Science and Mathematics SEs. "resource-recommendation" is one on Physics SE. I don't see how this is any less useful in this SE.

Comment: I would call this a "reference request" which is generally on topic most places.  However, it's extremely broad, can you narrow it down at all?

Comment: Yeah, it is quite broad. I can remove jazz and focus on classical music. Should I do more? The only way to narrow it down more is to focus in on, for instance, string instruments.

Comment: @Avatrin, indeed you should add some bounds... Maybe "classical" is too wide, try to define some precise periods...

Comment: @BCdotWEB, recommendations are on-topic : https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/649/bands-in-the-vein-of-dream-theater

Comment: @Bebs How is "are there any bands like this one" the same as "give me list of books and websites about really broad topic"? Plus: wouldn't this be more on topic @ https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history ?

Comment: Hi @BCdotWEB, I was answering to your comment *Asking for recommendations is usually off-topic*, I linked to a well accepted recommendation question. I wasn't saying that the two questions were the same.

Comment: @Bebs Hence me using the word "usually" -- I know about this site's particular exception. Also, you said "recommendations are on-topic" which is not what that meta question says at all; its scope is far more limited.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, you are right :-) I should have said "recommendations **can be** on-topic as long as they have enough boundaries so they are not too broad".

Comment: Alright, I have restricted it to 1400-1900. Is this too big a time period. I mean, have the instruments themselves really changed that much during this period?