# Looking for Prog Metal bands with big band instruments

Tags: jazz, metal, prog-metal

I recently fell in love with a band called [Thank You Scientist](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQ5GXMG2MuEMw_E_KQUELSA). They are an alternative prog rock band who use big-band instruments (brass, woodwinds, etc.) to back up their music.

I've been searching for prog *metal* bands with similar instrumentation but to no avail. The closest I've managed to find is [Icarus the Owl](https://www.youtube.com/user/Icarustheowl), who use similar chord progressions, vocal riffs, and guitar playing style. They don't quite qualify for the "metal" part though.

Are there any **metal** groups with a prog sound and jazz instruments?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this genre and apologize if this isn't what you are looking for, but a google search took to me to website that lists what they call their top "jazz metal" bands/artists: https://www.last.fm/tag/jazz+metal/artists

Comment: @DarthLocke I'll have to look through the list, thank you. I have discounted a couple of those already because they use jazz influenced harmony in their guitar writing, when I am looking for metal combined with big band instruments.

Comment: You might have better luck looking up symphonic metal. You may need to filter out the violins, though.

Comment: The [Diablo Swing Orchestra](https://open.spotify.com/artist/2cbWJP4X5b9sKEDW80uc5r?si=txLFjy7bSzijOZtwVdgLVg) combine jazz, swing, classical, and prog rock with metal. They're a bit avant-garde, but use jazz instrumentation nevertheless.

Comment: Related: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/649/bands-in-the-vein-of-dream-theater

Comment: Would metal still sound like metal played on big band instruments?

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-bands-that-fuse-metal-with-jazz-swing-and-make-it-sound-good https://www.reddit.com/r/Metal/comments/1iurwl/jazz_metal/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_u5txQJi6c

Comment: @ChrisSunami symphonic metal still sounds like metal with orchestral instruments thrown in

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy going back in time you might like Jethro Tull. They had their prog rock period in the 1970's. Then they went more mainstream. So albums like Aqualung [1971] or Thick as a Brick [1972] would be good; I listened to Thank You Scientist and I heard a Jethro Tull vibe; a possible influence even. The best Jethro Tull track to tell if you like them would probably be Heavy Horses. Actually I have listened to Jethro Tull's later 80's more mainstream music such as Budapest. I think that they are closer to what you want then. Heavy Horses [77] (older Jethro Tull] or Budapest [87] would be the tracks to see if they floated your boat.

Comment: +1 Jethro Tull was my immediate thought as well.

Answer (score 3):

Give Gentle Giant a listen.  They use brass, and they're about as Proggy as Prog and Prog.

Early Chicago is considered Prog, and they had a full horn section.

Weather Report might work for you as well.

Even Frank Zappa could be an interesting listen, as he has a very vast catalogue and his playing is unreal.  And he uses a Xylophone.  :-)

Comment: Love weather report! I remember trying to learn the bassline for Havona a few years ago. Didn't go well...

Comment: "Didn't go well" would be an understatement for me.  LOL!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how prog you want your prog rock, but some groups that come to mind that have at least some music in this wheelhouse are:

- [Oingo Boingo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jm-upHSP9KU) - I have a feeling this group may have been [a direct influence](http://www.prog-sphere.com/interviews/thank-you-scientist-interview/) on your band.
- [XTC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfRQGZUKS2Y) - This track was deliberately produced to sound like Latin jazz, but its core is pure prog, if you listen past the intro.
- [Tears For Fears](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAtGOESO7W8) - They started out with synths, but they had started adding creative instrumentation by their third album.
- [Chicago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUAYeN3Rp2E) - Their later work shaded over into easy listening, but they were still pretty hard rocking in their early days.
- [Dave Matthews Band](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNewq0V6aYE) - Often dismissed as noodlely jam-band frat-rock, DMB has some gems buried among their deep tracks.

I know you specified "prog *metal*" in your question, but honestly, I'm not hearing a lot of metal in your referenced groups.

Comment: "I'm not hearing a lot of metal in your referenced groups" that's why I'm looking for metal groups!

Comment: Oh, I totally misread your question then.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Coppelius", from Germany, quite unknown band and fits with your description!
Wikipedia info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppelius
You can also check Panzerballett, also from Germany: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzerballett

Comment: This answer is a bit thin. Can you add links to some of their music or some more information about them?

Comment: added wikipedia link